# NLog support of EventLog SuccessAudit and FailureAudit

Tags: logging, nlog, event-log

How can you setup the NLog configuration file to support both `EventLogEntryType.SuccessAudit` and `EventLogEntryType.FailureAudit` when writing to the Windows EventLog.

There is a posting on their github page that says that this is possible, but I'm having problems setting the `entryType` attribute to support `SuccessAudit` and `FailureAudit`.

Here is the `<targets>` section of my `NLog.config`:

```xml
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="EventLog"
        name="EventLogTarget"
        source="MySource"
        layout="${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${logger} | ${message}"
        entryType=""
        log="CustomLog">
    </target>
</targets>
```

Any ideas on what to put in the `entryType` ??

Answer (score 1):

`entryType` is converted from the string-value into the [EventLogEntryType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentrytype.aspx) enum-value.

I'm guessing you have some condition that tells whether it is SuccessAudit or FailureAudit.

Lets say the LogLevel was the condition, then it could be like this:

```
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="EventLog"
        name="EventLogTarget"
        source="MySource"
        layout="${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${logger} | ${message}"
        entryType="${when:when=level<=LogLevel.Info:inner=SuccessAudit:else=FailureAudit}"
        log="CustomLog">
    </target>
</targets>
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the when conditional idea.